# Can multiple domains be routed to different CodeIgniter modules or controllers?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dns

Is it possible to have two domains in one CodeIgniter application routed to two different modules or controllers?

**Example:**

- `login.example.com` for controller auth/login
- `love.example.com` for controller love/index

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? You can have 2 domains in your vhost, so it uses the same project.

Comment: Surely its possible, you can check for the domain name to which the request was made like this `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, then you can respond accordingly.

Comment: thanks bro , i think i miss understanding about base_url before, thats simple like i create more base_url :D